# Resolve recurrence relation from function

Tags: algorithm, relation, recurrence

The function Dots prints dots on screen:

```
Dots(n)
  if n==1 then
    Write(.)
  else
    for i=1 to n-1 do
      Dots(i)
    for i=1 to n do
      for j=1 to n do
        Write(.)
```

How many dots will be printed for n?

Comment: I would first run the program for different n to get a first idea. And than try to validate my educated guess by analyzing the code.

Comment: There is no image.  Edit the post to explain your "everything".

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation for counting number of dots is like.

```
if n > 1
    T(n) = T(1) + ... + T(n-1) + n ^ 2
else 
    T(n) = 1
```

You can write the below function to find the number of dots:

```
def Dots(n):
  if n==1:
    return 1
  else:
    dots = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
      dots += Dots(i)
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
      for j in range(1, n + 1):
        dots += 1
    return dots

for i in range(1, 6):
  print(i, "dots =", Dots(i))
```

OUTPUT

```
1 dots = 1
2 dots = 5
3 dots = 15
4 dots = 37
5 dots = 83
```

Comment: Ok, so it is the same what I have got. And for this I've made transformation:
T(n) - n^2 = T(1) + ... + T(n-1),

T(n+1) = T(1) + ... + T(n-1) + T(n) + (n+1)^2,

and by substitution:

T(n+1) = T(n) - n^2 + T(n) + (n+1)^2,

T(n+1) = 2T(n) + 2n +1,

and for n=n-1 for this I've got:

T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 2(n-1) + 1,

and I stuck at this point. What can I resolve this recurrence relation. And am I correct at this point?

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite the code as a function that computes the number of dots:

```
D(n)
  if n==1 then
    return 1
  else
    Count= 0
    for i=1 to n-1 do
      Count+= D(i)
    for i=1 to n do
      for j=1 to n do
        Count++
    return Count
```

This corresponds to the recurrence

```
D(1) = 1
D(n) = Σ(i= 1, n-1) D(i) + n²
```

We can rework as follows to bring it in a more familiar form:

```
D(n) = D(n-1) + Σ(i= 1, n-2) D(i) + n² = 2D(n-1) + 2n - 1.
```

The rest is routine work. Multiplying by `2^(-n)`,

```
2^(-n)D(n) = 2^(-(n-1))D(n-1) + 2^(-n)(2n - 1)
```

and you obtain `2^(-n)D(n)` by summation.